# Android: replaceAll() and double quote issue issue

Tags: android, regex

I dont know where I m going wrong.. I want to replace `"` with `""`
I have used the following code.

```
input.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"");
```

this doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so when you "change" your string, you need to reassign it.

```
input = input.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, so you need to assign it into another String:

```
input = input.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"");
```